# Why is my F# vector add function using tail recursion not working?

Tags: recursion, vector, f#

I cannot get this to work in F#.  I am trying to write a tail recursive form of vector add and pass the previously calculated values using a.  It is giving error "error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
    ''a'
but given a
    ''b list -> 'c list -> 'a list'
The types ''a' and ''b list -> 'c list -> 'a list' cannot be unified."

```
let rec vecadd a v1 v2 =
 match (v1, v2) with
 | ([], []) -> a
 | (h1::t1, h2::t2) -> vecadd a::h1+h2 t1 t2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you need to add parentheses around `(a::h1+h2)`. Otherwise, the compiler thinks that you are calling `vecadd` with `a` as the argument
and then prepending that to a list. Your code gets parsed as `(vecadd a)::h1+h2` instead.

Once you add the parentheses, there is one more issue. In your recursive call, the argument `a::h1+h2` is not right - the operator `::` prepends a value to the front of a list and so it takes a value and a list of values. In your case, you are trying to use it to append a value to the end of the list.

You can fix this by using `h1+h2::a` to add the new element to the front of the list and then reversing the list before returning it in the `[], []` case:

```
let rec vecadd a v1 v2 =
 match (v1, v2) with
 | ([], []) -> List.rev a
 | (h1::t1, h2::t2) -> vecadd (h1+h2::a) t1 t2
```